# SDL2_image C# Couldn't open file.png

Tags: c#, .net, sdl-2

When trying to load a texture into the console, the output is: Couldn't open lettuce.png
I tried to upload both jpg files and webp. Changed SDL flags. But nothing helped.
There are no problems with initializing SDL
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6E7w.png)
If anyone has met with such a tell me.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using SDL2;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GGG
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            if (SDL.SDL_Init(SDL.SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL.SDL_INIT_EVENTS) < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error SDL2 Initialization : " + SDL.SDL_GetError());
            }
            
            if (SDL_image.IMG_Init(SDL_image.IMG_InitFlags.IMG_INIT_PNG) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error SDL2_image Initialization : " + SDL_image.IMG_GetError());
            }
            
            IntPtr window = SDL.SDL_CreateWindow("Pizda", 10, 10, 800, 800, SDL.SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
            if (window == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error window creation");
            }

            IntPtr render = SDL.SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if (render == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error renderer creation");
            }

            IntPtr texture = SDL_image.IMG_LoadTexture(render, "lettuce.png");
            if (texture == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error texture load : " + SDL_image.IMG_GetError());
            }

            if (SDL.SDL_RenderClear(render) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error render clear : " + SDL.SDL_GetError());
            }

            if (SDL.SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error render copy : " + SDL.SDL_GetError());
            }

            SDL.SDL_RenderPresent(render);

            while (true)
            {
                SDL.SDL_Event e;
                if (SDL.SDL_PollEvent(out e) == 1)
                {
                    if (e.type == SDL2.SDL.SDL_EventType.SDL_QUIT)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            SDL.SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL.SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
            SDL.SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_image.IMG_Quit();
            SDL.SDL_Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

SDL2_image.dll and SDL2.dll and the image is in a package with an executable file.

Comment: Are you sure that you are working in the right directory?